# How to cancel update messages from a changed plugin

Tags: plugin-development, updates

I did many changes on an plugin which was allowed to be manipulated.

Now I want to be sure, that an update will not overwrite all my changes.
What can I do to prohibit it from updating (or showing the update message, so that no other admin updates it unintended)?

the rest of the system shell still be able to be updated

Answer (score 3):

The quick and easy method to do this is to edit the Version.
For example if the version no. is 1.1.2 edit to make it to 100.1.2.
Hence your plugin will not ask you to update itself unless it reachess the version no. 100.1.2.
You can edit this version no. in the plugins main php file.

```
 <?php
  /**
  * Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
  * Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
  * Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
  * Version: 100.1.2
  * Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
  * Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
  * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
  */
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I +1 it. Is there a way which goes without due date, even if it is in the far future? Where to deactivate the updating completely (I ask this now for board-quality reasons, but I can live with that solution)